# How to get the JSON data sent from ajax and parsing to variable

Tags: json, ajax, go, go-gin

I use jquery to send ajax json data for golang web restful service. And want to parse the json data in my backend using golang. Here is simple javascript code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/persons",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "data": '{"firstName": "Hello","lastName": "World"}' 
        },
        success:function (res) {
            console.log(res)
        },
        error: function (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
```

Then use GetRawData() to get the gin.Context information, and a json decoder to parse the json content,

```
data, _ := c.GetRawData()
jsonStream := string(data)
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream))

t, err := dec.Token()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for dec.More() {
    var p Person
    err := dec.Decode(&p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Hello %s\n", p.firstName)
}
```

Done!

Comment: What exactly are you googling _for_?  A simple search for "golang json" should give you everything you need to know.

Comment: @Flimzy I've got my solution by goggle "golang json", thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very familiar with Gin, but to accept `application/json` data, use `gin.Context.BindJSON` to bind the values in the request.

```
router.POST("/persons", func(c *gin.Context) {
  var jsonData Member
  if c.BindJSON(&jsonData) == nil {
    fmt.Println(jsonData.first_name + " " + jsonData.last_name)
  } else {
    // handle error

  }
}
```

Updating with Peter's suggestion for exporting the fields:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName  string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName   string    `json:"last_name"`
}
```

Comment: Struct fields must be exported though.

Comment: @Peter such as this? `   type Person struct {
        FirstName  string `json:"first_name"`
        LastName   string    `json:"last_name"`
    }`

Comment: Yes, like this.